# add spinner during and call and check after call

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am trying to add a spinner icon during the my function call and then after the call to return a check mark image:

My issue is that I m not updating the loading or check icon according to the callback but instead i m mocking it on a timeout. How can I display the loading icon during the save function and then check after the function resolves?

```
function save() {
 successMessage()
 new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout( function() {
    resolve("Success!")
  }, 250) 
}) 
}
function createIcon(src, title) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = src;
  img.className = 'icon'
  img.style.display = 'none'
  if (title != null) {
    img.title = title
    img.alt = title
  }
  if (src.indexOf('spinner') > 0) img.classList.add('spin')
  return img;
}
function successMessage() {
  let el = document.querySelector('button')
  let check = this.createIcon("check.svg", "Updated")
  let spinner = this.createIcon("spinner.svg", "Updating...")

  if (el.childNodes.length === 1) {
    el.appendChild(spinner)
    el.appendChild(check)
  }

  check.style.display = 'none'
  spinner.style.display = 'initial'
  setTimeout(function() {
    spinner.style.display = 'none'
    check.style.display = 'initial'
  }, 500);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/61y4whLs/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will show statuses of loading and done when the save button is click. You can replace the word to icon or images accordingly.

```js
function save() {
  
  let save = document.getElementById("save");
  
  save.innerHTML = 'Loading...'; // to replace anything you want when  loading

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( function() {
      resolve("Success!")
    }, 2500) 
  }).then(function(){
  
    save.innerHTML = 'Done'; // to replace anything you want to show status completed
    
  }) 
}
```

```html
<button id="save" onclick="save()">
Hello
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an asynchronous operation steps, it can be returned and called by using `then`.

And, Does it need to create img element for icons dynamically? `Button` element can be contained child nodes as HTML.

The following code are forked from yours:

http://jsfiddle.net/oqs9wdh0/

you clicked button, then it shows spinner and success icon in a second later.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('button')
let check = el.querySelector('.icon.check')
let spinner = el.querySelector('.icon.spin')
  
function save() {
    // show spinner
  check.style.display = 'none'
  spinner.style.display = 'initial'
  
  // success after a second
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("Success!")
    }, 1000)
  })
}

function successMessage(result) {
  // hide and show
  spinner.style.display = 'none'
  check.style.display = 'initial'
  alert(result)
}
```

```css
button > img.icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="save().then(successMessage)">
  Hello
  <img src="check.svg" class="icon check" alt="Successfully updated">
  <img src="spinner.svg" class="icon spin" alt="Updating...">
</button>
```